# Tree navigation with XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, treeview

I have this tree structured XML (toc.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toc>
  <item name="top" key="4294967296" subkey="1">
    <item name="child1" key="4294967611" subkey="">
      <item name="child2-1" key="4294961611" subkey="">
        <item name="child3-1" key="4294967613" subkey=""/>
        <item name="child3-2" key="4294967612" subkey=""/>
      </item>
      <item name="child2-2" key="4294962611" subkey="">
        <item name="d" key="4294974806" subkey=""/>
      </item>
      <item name="child2-3" key="4294963611" subkey="">
        <item name="d" key="4294967661" subkey=""/>
        <item name="PI" key="4294967659" subkey=""/>
        <item name="q" key="4294967660" subkey=""/>
      </item>
      <item name="child2-4" key="4294964611" subkey=""/>
      <item name="child2-5" key="4294965611" subkey="">
        <item name="bb" key="4294967616" subkey=""/>
        <item name="bb" key="4294967620" subkey=""/>
        <item name="f" key="4294967615" subkey=""/>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
</toc>
```

Each key will be unique in the document.

I have an XSLT that imports the toc XML and tries to output the navigation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="/member/@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/member">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="/member/name"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="navigation">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="document('toc.xml')" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl>
```

And would like to find a node and output the following HTML inside the HTML file:

```
...html...
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">top</a><ul>
      <li><a href="#">child1</li><ul>
        <li><a href="#">child2</li><ul>
            <li><a href="#">child3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">child3-2</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        </ul></li>
      </ul></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...more html...
```

Basically I want to search for a node: item[@key='4294967611'] and output all of the parent nodes and the direct children.

I feel this should be really easy but I'm struggling to find information about how to do this. My XSLT knowledge isn't great.

Comment: in your input child2 occurs multiple times with different children (e.g. bb) that don't occur in your output.  Is that a copypasta error?  Is child2 meant to be unique?

Comment: sorry, yes child2 was entered to indicate the depth but names are unique. I will update the question.

Comment: Are you intending to pass the key as a parameter to the xslt?

Comment: See my answer for a solution to what I think is your problem. Whenever you correct your question I'd be willing to give it a +1.

Comment: I have edited my question, hopefully that will make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the provided input (with no unique `@key`), this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="key" select="4294967611"/>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="generate-id() =
                            generate-id(../item[@key=$key][1])
                            and
                            not(item[@key=$key])">
                <xsl:call-template name="chain">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="ancestor-or-self::item"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="childs" select="item"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="chain">
        <xsl:param name="parents"/>
        <xsl:param name="childs"/>
        <xsl:if test="$parents">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$parents[1]/@name"/>
                    </a>
                    <xsl:call-template name="chain">
                        <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="$parents[position()!=1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="childs" select="$childs"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:if test="count($parents)=1">
                        <ul>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$childs">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:if>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">top</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">child1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">child2-1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">child3-1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">child3-2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If `@key` were unique, this stylesheet should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="itemBykey" match="item" use="@key"/>
    <xsl:param name="key" select="4294967611"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('itemBykey',$key)">
            <xsl:call-template name="chain">
                <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="ancestor-or-self::item"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="childs" select="item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="chain">
        <xsl:param name="parents"/>
        <xsl:param name="childs"/>
        <xsl:if test="$parents">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$parents[1]/@name"/>
                    </a>
                    <xsl:call-template name="chain">
                        <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="$parents[position()!=1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="childs" select="$childs"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:if test="count($parents)=1">
                        <ul>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$childs">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:if>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. The unique key one works like a charm. How would you add the subkey to the key in "select="key('itemBykey',$key)"?

Comment: @Barry Jones: You're wellcome. About your question: now the key would be @key plus @subkey, so the xsl:key/@use should be `concat(@key,'some-character-not-present-in-keys',@subkey)` and the `key()` function should be invoque like `key('itemBykey',concat($key,'some-character-not-present-in-keys',$subkey))` with $subkey been a new param added.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but just having a little trouble here.

I used:
 key('itemByKey', concat($key, '-', $subKey)

But is just doesnt work even when I use it on both the select and the key defenition:
<xsl:key name="itemBykey" match="item" use="concat(@key, '-', @subKey)"/>

and select:
key('itemBykey',concat($id, '-', $subId))

Where $id and $subId are declared as:
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="/member/@id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="subId" select="/member/@subId"/>

Comment: @Barry Jones: Check your names (in your sample is @subkey not @subKey) and your input. Those changes works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implementation with the proper parent-child hierarchy for the **ul** and **li** elements. It will output only those nodes that are parents or direct children of value for key given in the xsl:variable keyVar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"    >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name ="keyVar" select="'4294967666'" />

  <xsl:template match="toc">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <a href="#" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <xsl:if test ="count(descendant::item) > 0">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="item[.//@key=$keyVar or ../@key = $keyVar]" />
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ul>
  <li>top<ul>
    <li>child1<ul>
      <li>child2-1<ul>
        <li>child3-1</li>
        <li>child3-2</li>
      </ul></li>
      <li>child2-2<ul>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul></li>
      <li>child2-3<ul>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>PI</li>
        <li>q</li>
      </ul></li>
      <li>child2-4</li>
      <li>child2-5<ul>
        <li>bb</li>
        <li>bb</li>
        <li>f</li>
      </ul></li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. By direct children I meant only the level directly under the selected node. So if child-1 was selected it would only show the child2-1, child2-2 etc. Also, this appears to output every single top level item i.e. /toc/item

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the provided wanted output is not well-formed XML document or fragment.

Also, there is no `<item name="child2" ...>` element in the provided source XML document.

Also, there are six `item` elements with `key='4294967611'`, so this also isn't a usable criterion for identifying the element.

**I think, you want this**:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">top</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">child1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">child2-1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">child3-1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">child3-2</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**If my *guess* is correct, here is one possible solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pEl" select="//item[@name='child2-1']"/>

 <xsl:template match="toc">
   <xsl:variable name="pChain" select="$pEl/ancestor-or-self::item"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pChain[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pChain" select="$pChain"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pEndElementId" select="generate-id($pEl)"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:param name="pChain" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="pcurPosition" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="pEndElementId"/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="generate-id() = $pEndElementId">
          <ul>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="leafChildren"/>
          </ul>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="$pChain[position()=$pcurPosition+1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pChain" select="$pChain"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pcurPosition" select="$pcurPosition +1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pEndElementId" select="$pEndElementId"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="leafChildren">
  <li><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<toc>
<item name="top" key="4294967296" subkey="1">
    <item name="child1" key="4294967611" subkey="">
        <item name="child2-1" key="4294967611" subkey="">
            <item name="child3-1" key="4294967613" subkey=""/>
            <item name="child3-2" key="4294967612" subkey=""/>
        </item>
        <item name="child2-2" key="4294967611" subkey="">
            <item name="d" key="4294974806" subkey=""/>
        </item>
        <item name="child2-3" key="4294967611" subkey="">
            <item name="d" key="4294967661" subkey=""/>
            <item name="PI" key="4294967659" subkey=""/>
            <item name="q" key="4294967660" subkey=""/>
        </item>
        <item name="child2-4" key="4294967611" subkey=""/>
        <item name="child2-5" key="4294967611" subkey="">
            <item name="bb" key="4294967616" subkey=""/>
            <item name="bb" key="4294967620" subkey=""/>
            <item name="f" key="4294967615" subkey=""/>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
</toc>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">top</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="#">child1</a>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">child2-1</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">child3-1</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">child3-2</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In case my guess about the wanted result was not a hit, please, correct your question and provide a well-formed output.