# XSLT Navigation Menu

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, tree, navigation

I have a question on XSL-Transformation (XSLT-1). I am trying it since days, but I didn't get it to work.

I want to build a standard website tree navigation with XML and XSLT-1. It should only show the items on the path to the current item. if the current item has child-items, the next node should be opened.

My XML source is like this:

```
<cat>
    <item id="0" name="1">
        <item id="1" name="1.1"></item>
        <item id="2" name="1.2"></item>
        <item id="3" name="1.3"></item>
        <item id="4" name="1.4">
            <item id="5" name="1.4.1">
                <item id="6" name="1.4.1.1"></item>
                <item id="7" name="1.4.1.2"></item>
                <item id="8" name="1.4.1.3"></item>
            </item>
            <item id="9" name="1.4.2"></item>
            <item id="10" name="1.4.3"></item>
        </item>
        <item id="11" name="1.5"></item>
        <item id="12" name="1.6"></item>
    </item>
    <item id="13" name="2">
        <item id="14" name="2.1"></item>
        <item id="15" name="2.2"></item>
    </item>
    <item id="16" name="3"></item>
</cat>
```

Now I want to call a page with an $pageid=7 send by URL, and it should show some output like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
            <li>1.3</li>
            <li>1.4
                <ul>
                    <li>1.4.1
                        <ul>
                            <li>1.4.1.1</li>
                            <li class="activeitem">1.4.1.2</li>
                            <li>1.4.1.3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>1.4.2</li>
                    <li>1.4.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>1.5</li>
            <li>1.6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

If I call a page with an $pageid=4 send by URL, and it should show some output like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
            <li>1.3</li>
            <li class="activeitem">1.4
                <ul>
                    <li>1.4.1</li>
                    <li>1.4.2</li>
                    <li>1.4.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>1.5</li>
            <li>1.6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully my example is understandable for all.

I already got a sitemap and a breadcrumb navigation working, but this one seems to be very tricky and experienced.

I tried to modify the examples from [Tree navigation with XML and XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385792/tree-navigation-with-xml-and-xslt) - but it didn't worked well. It only shows the path to the item, but not the rest.

Can somebody experienced with XSLT-1 help me with it?

Or maybe somebody has already a working solution to post here?

It would be very kind. Thank you all for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge here is to find the correct test for navigating inside a new list. For a given list item, I think you are searching for this kind of test (not really obvious):

```
 "item and .//@id=$pageid"
```

Check this transform out.

[XSLT 1.0]

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pageid" select="4"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="Navigate"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Navigate">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/cat/item" mode="Navigate"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="Navigate">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@id[.=$pageid]" mode="Navigate"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:if test="item and .//@id=$pageid">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="Navigate"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@id" mode="Navigate">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="'activeitem'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

result for $pageid = 4:

```
<ul>
   <li>1<ul>
         <li>1.1</li>
         <li>1.2</li>
         <li>1.3</li>
         <li class="activeitem">1.4<ul>
               <li>1.4.1</li>
               <li>1.4.2</li>
               <li>1.4.3</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>1.5</li>
         <li>1.6</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

result for $pageid=7:

```
<ul>
   <li>1<ul>
         <li>1.1</li>
         <li>1.2</li>
         <li>1.3</li>
         <li>1.4<ul>
               <li>1.4.1<ul>
                     <li>1.4.1.1</li>
                     <li class="activeitem">1.4.1.2</li>
                     <li>1.4.1.3</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>1.4.2</li>
               <li>1.4.3</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>1.5</li>
         <li>1.6</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

result for $pageid=13:

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li class="activeitem">2<ul>
         <li>2.1</li>
         <li>2.2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Eddy Thanks for the feedback I've updated the question accordingly. Now ascending/descending order is supported and adapted to `xsl:call-template`. Note I've used template modes to simplify recursion.

Comment: Many many thanks to you @empo!

This one is working very well and I would never found the hook with the "mode" - attribut by myself. I learned something very important to know!

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is that if an item has the selected page as a descendent, or is the selected page, then you want to see all child items of for that item.

Here is my attempt...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="pageNum" select="13" />

   <xsl:template match="/cat">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <li>
         <xsl:if test="@id=$pageNum">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">activeitem</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="descendant-or-self::item[@id=$pageNum] and count(node()) > 0">
               <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates />
               </ul>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For 4 and 7 the expected output is as shown in the question. For 13, the output is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="activeitem">2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you are true with the wanted logic. I've probably misunderstood the requirement. +1

Comment: I've fixed my test condition accordingly. Why using `xsl:choose` when you only have one single test?

Comment: @empo Yes, you are correct! When I started writing it, I was thinking I would need a separate conditions for descendants and for matching the item itself. In the end I combined the tests into one, but neglected to make it an xsl:if

Comment: At first I have to thank you for your work @empo and Tim C, but I didn't get this to work.

I need a version to include by call-template, not by assign-tamplates. The version of empo seems to work only, if the id is in an ascending order.

Now I tried something like this, but I don't get the real recursion working.

    <xsl:template name="treenav">
        <ul>
            <xsl:call-template name="treenavnode">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="/db/cat/item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: <xsl:template name="treenavnode">
<xsl:param name="nodes"/>
<li><a href="{$nodes/@id}"><xsl:value-of select="$nodes/@name"/></a>
<xsl:if test="$nodes/descendant-or-self::category[@id=$pageid] and count($nodes/node()) &gt; 0">
<ul>
<xsl:call-template name="treenavnode">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes/descendant::category"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</ul>
</xsl:if>
</li>
</xsl:template>

Maybe there is a solution with a choose section or for-each. I tried both in different ways, but I get only crap or infinite loops.