# XSLT nested list items

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to xslt, I trying to deal with a situation where I have nested unordered or ordered list items
 eg:

```
*  Dresses
          # Formal
                -  Men
                -  Women
                - Children
          # Casual
     *  FootWear
     *  Other Accessories
```

Basically the list items are nested one within other but we they can nested as deep as it can be. Can you give me a general idea on how to achieve this..

Edith says: Thanks for your quick response.Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<emailmessage>
    <ul>
        <li>Dresses</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Professional</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Mens</li>
                <li>Womens</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Causual </li>
        </ul>
        <li>FootWear</li>
        <li>Other Accessories</li>
    </ul>
</emailmessage>
```

This is my xml in html type, the format is something I want to attain in plain text i.e

- One tab and `*` if its `<li>` without any ancestor
- two tabs and `#` if its sublist of first one i.e one having one ancestor
- three tabs with `-` if its sublist of sublist i.e has two ancestors.

And the format repeats..

```
* Dresses
    # Formal
        - Men
        - Women
        - Children
    # Casual
* FootWear
* Other Accessories
```

Comment: It would help if You posted an example. (Origin xml and wanted xml.)

Comment: Are the signs (*,#, -) really present in your input document?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution that is the shortest so far, consist of a single template and is so generic that it handles any level of nesting, up to 20. :)

Comment: Also added an updated solution that works successfully with unlimited nesting. :)

Comment: the  *, #,- are something we need to add to the plain text in order to diffrentiate between parent lists and sublists...

Comment: the * , # , - are not actually present, I have to add them if its first li of ul or ol , I need a tab and *, if its child of ul or ol that is within the first list then it will be 2 tabs and # and so on. Sorry for confusion

Comment: See my updated solution, that now, in addition to handling unlimited nesting, also correctly selects one of the three marking characters, as you have indicated that these aren't part of the source XML document.

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation works with any level of nestedness, up to 20**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vIndent"
  select="'&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="li">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(substring($vIndent,1, count(ancestor::ul)+1),.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<emailmessage>
    <ul>
        <li>* Dresses</li>
        <ul>
            <li># Professional</li>
            <ul>
                <li>- Mens</li>
                <li>- Womens</li>
            </ul>
            <li># Causual </li>
        </ul>
        <li>* FootWear</li>
        <li>* Other Accessories</li>
    </ul>
</emailmessage>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
* Dresses
    # Professional
        - Mens
        - Womens
    # Causual 
* FootWear
* Other Accessories
```

**Update**: ***unlimited* nesting**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="li">
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ul"><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update2**: The OP has indicated that the marking characters (*, *, and -) aren't present in the XML document. Here is the solution that works with unlimited nesting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDelims" select="'- * # '"/>

 <xsl:template match="li">
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ul"><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($vDelims,
              2*(1+count(ancestor::ul) mod 3) -1,
              2)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document (as above but with bullet characters removed)**:

```
<emailmessage>
    <ul>
        <li>Dresses</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Professional</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Mens</li>
                <li>Womens</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Causual </li>
        </ul>
        <li>FootWear</li>
        <li>Other Accessories</li>
    </ul>
</emailmessage>
```

**the same, wanted and correct result is produced**:

```
* Dresses
    # Professional
        - Mens
        - Womens
    # Causual 
* FootWear
* Other Accessories
```

Comment: this does not work ..
This is xsl:
<xsl:template match="li">
 <xsl:variable name="symbols" select="'- * # '"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ul"><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($symbols,2*(1+count(ancestor::ul) mod 3) -1,2)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
the xml:<ul><li>Dresses<ul><li>Casual</li><li>Professional</li></ul></li><li>other Accessories </li></ul>

Comment: @user916625: What do you mean by "does not work"? I always test my code before posting it in answers. If you apply the transformation in my code to the XML document in my answer, you must get the same result that I get. If you don't get this result the reason may be either: You have changed the XSLT code; or: you have changed the XML document; or: both; or: you are using a buggy, incompliant XSLT processor.

Comment: maybe its because the ul is part of larger xml that has other tags like div, h1 etc...

Comment: @user916625: If this is the case you have to ask a new, more "representative" question. The question you asked has been fully answered.

Comment: You are right...I will post question shortly.It works with the xml I posted but not with entire file

Answer (score 2):

Count the **ul** ancestors on template match (note that the first one does not need it). This transform should give you a good starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="emailmessage/ul/li">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;*',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[count(ancestor::ul)=2]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;&#09;#',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[count(ancestor::ul)=3]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;&#09;'&#09;-',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
* Dresses
    # Professional
        - Mens
        - Womens
    # Causual 
* FootWear
* Other Accessories
```

Comment: Both of the answers are superb!!!! I will try both..I was going after using using named template and doing a recursive call. I really appreciate both of you for elping me...

Comment: Well solution is still the same (see my answer now). What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020103/xslt-navigation-menu) can be helpful? It shows how to build a tree-navigation for a website with XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Here is my xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<emailmessage>
<ul>
<li>* Dresses</li>
   <ul>
       <li># Professional</li>
            <ul>
              <li>- Mens</li>
              <li>- Womens</li>
     </ul>

       <li># Causual </li>
    </ul>

<li>* FootWear</li>
<li>* Other Accessories</li>
</ul>
</emailmessage>

Comment: This is my xml in html type , the format is something I want to attain in plain text i.e One tab and * if its <li> without any ancestor, two tabs and # if its sublist of first one i.e one having one ancestor and three tabs with  - if its  sublist of sublist i.e has two ancestors. And the format repeats..
*  Dresses
          # Formal
                -  Men
                -  Women
                - Children
          # Casual
     *  FootWear
     *  Other Accessories